# Count start and end html tags

Tags: php, html, tags, count, validation

I'm looking for a way to count html tags in a chunk of html using php.  This may not be a full web page with a doctype body tags etc.

For example:

If I had something like this

```
$string = "
<div></div>
<div style='blah'></div>
<p>hello</p>
<p>its debbie mcgee
<p class='pants'>missing p above</p>
<div></div>";
```

I want to pass it to a function with a tag name such as

CheckHtml( $string, 'p' );

and I would like it to tell me the number of open `<p>` tags and the number of close p tags `</p>`.  I don't want it to do anything fancy beyond that (no sneaky trying to fix it).

I have tried with string counts with start tags such as `<p` but it can too easily find things like  and return wrong results.

I had a look as DOMDocument but it doesn't seem to count close tags and always expects `<html>` tags (although I could work around this).

Any suggestions on what to use.

Comment: Note that to check the validity of your document, you not only need to have as many opening tags as closing tags (regardless of autoclosing tags), but the tags must be *correctly nested*. i.e. `<p><div></p></div>` is not valid.

Comment: What you say is absolutely correct, Idealy I would like it to check for those sorts of errors as well.....but for the moment I would be happy with checking tags.... unless I can see an way to get DOMDocument or XMLReader to do it.  Just trying to count the tags as I have gives lots of opportunities for errors.  esp if its a 'novice' writing the html

Answer (score 1):

To get a accurate count, you can't use string matching or regex because of the [well-known problems of parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Nor can you use the output of a standard parser, because that's a DOM consisting of elements and all the information about the tags that were in the HTML has been discarded. End tags will be inferred even for valid HTML, and even some start tags (e.g. html, head, body, tbody) can be inferred. Moreover things like [the adoption agency algorithm](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.html#adoptionAgency) can result in there being more elements than there were tags in the HTML mark-up. For example `<b><i></b>x</i>` will result in there being two `i` elements in the DOM. At the same time, end tags that can't be matched with start tags are simply discarded, as indeed can start and end tags that appear in the wrong place. (e.g. `<caption>` not in `<table>` or `<legend>` not in `<fieldset>`)

The only way I can think you could do this in any way reliably is this:

There's an open source PHP library for parsing HTML called [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/).

In there, there's a file called `Tokenizer.php` and at the end of that file there's a function called `emitToken`. At this point, the parser has done all the work of figuring out all the HTML weirdnesses¹, and the `$token` parameter contains all the information about what kind of token has been recognised, including start and end tags.

You could take the library and modify it so that it counts up the start and end tag tokens at that point, and then exposes those totals to your application code at the end of the parse process.

---

¹: That is, it's figured out the weirdnesses related to your counting problem. It hasn't *begun* to figure out the tree construction weirdnesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/function.substr-count.php) to return the number of times the needle substring occurs in the haystack `$string`.

```
$open_tag_count = substring_count( $string, '<p' );
$close_tag_count = substring_count( $string, '</p>' );
```

Be aware that '<param and `<pre`, so you may need to modify your search to handle two different specific cases:

```
$open_tag_count_without_attributes = substring_count( $string, '<p>' );
$open_tag_count_with_attributes = substring_count( $string, '<p ' );

$open_tag_count = $open_tag_count_without_attributes + $open_tag_count_with_attributes;
```

You may also wish to consider using `[preg_match()][1]`. Using a regular expression to parse HTML comes with a [fairly substantial set of pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454), so use with caution.

Comment: substr_count is what I am trying at the moment... it worked until I gave it a page that had <param> on it.  It picked it up as the start of the <p> tag giving the wrong results.

Comment: Using this method, you should include a space after the open tag, to prevent issues like the `<p` vs `<param` thing.

Comment: @Steve, please see my updated answer for a workaround. Jeffrey, we must also consider cases where the tag uses no attributes, so including a space is only part of the answer.

Comment: What about tags with a TAB (as opposed to a SPACE) between the element name and the first attribute?

Comment: @Bobby Jack, one could certainly code for that (`"\t"`), but who uses tabs within HTML tags?

Comment: @George: I'm sure the chances of it are pretty unlikely and, if the outcome of it 'slipping through the filter' isn't disastrous, then maybe that's satisfactory. It's more an illustration of a wider point: to do this robustly, you really need to parse the HTML.

Comment: @Bobby Jack: I agree with your wider point, and therefore add this caveat to my answer: This code will work for the given input, and other input very much like it. If a broader scope is needed, I recommend the OP define it.

Answer (score 0):

substr_count seems like a good bet.

EDIT: You'll have to use preg_match then

I haven't tested, this but, for an idea..

```
function checkHTML($string,$htmlTag){
  $openTags = preg_match('/<'.$htmlTag.'\b[^>]*>',$string);
  $closeTags = preg_match('/<\/'.$htmlTag.'>/',$string);
  return array($openTags, $closeTags);
}

$numberOfParagraphTags = checkHTML($string,'p');

echo('Open Tags:'.$numberOfParagraphTags[0].' Close Tags:'.$numberOfParagraphTags[1]);
```

Comment: substr_count is what I am trying at the moment... it worked until I gave it a page that had <param> on it. It picked it up as the start of the <p> tag giving the wrong results.

Comment: Wrapping this in a function seems best for sure. I'd again argue for appending a space to the text we are checking in `substr_count()`

Comment: The <p> tag could be arranged as <p class='somestuff'> or <p>  so I would have to search for '<p ' and <p>.

Comment: @Steve, the regex takes that into account, it will match <p class='somestuff'> and <p> and even <p flobabdobbainvalidhtmlattr>

Comment: Yeah, I will give it a blast tomorrow.  see how it works with what I am trying now... (domdocument vs substr_count).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not quite that simple. What about uppercase tags? What about close tags with space before the final angle bracket (believe it or not, that's valid HTML)? What about things that will match that regexp, but aren't actually tags, such as the contents of a comment, or an attribute value? If you really need this to be 100% robust (which you might well not), you need to be parsing that HTML properly (see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html for a great article from Jeff about this very issue).

Answer (score 0):

For the chunk of HTML, try using the `DomDocument` PHP class instead of a string.  Then you can use methods such as `getElementsByTagName();` that will allow you to count the tags easier and more accurately.  To load your string into a `DomDocument`, you could do something like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
```

Then, to count your tags, do the following:

```
$tagList = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tag);
return $tagList.length;
```

Comment: Had a go with that, liked it haven't finished testing....  One thing about it though it doesn't count end tags and I would still have to do some sort of string count.  Easily fooled if there are comments in the code etc :o(. Was kind of wondering if XMLReader could do this?

Comment: I like Alohci's suggestion best, although I'm sure XMLReader could do the job.